# How to view binary PDF documents on an android device

Tags: android, pdf

We have a serious problem to tackle here. We are loading pdf documents as binaries into our application and need to be able to view them. Due to security reasons we are not allowed to store them on an external storage.

Our investigations showed that adobe reader x does not support handling binaries and can only digest physical links to a document. This means, it is not an option for us.

Is it correct that Google does not provide a native API to view PDF documents? We could not find any evidence.

Only option left is to implement either our own pdf viewer activity or integrating an existing library.

Are our findings correct? If so, could somebody point out a suggestion on how to proceed here? Are there any ressources available enabling us to implement our own viewer?

We are currently looking at using: http://code.google.com/p/apv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/readermobile.html. RMSDK supports everything that Adobe Reader built on top of it supports. Though, I wonder why the security? Why can't you generate password protected PDFs or livecycle protected ones? What is there to stop people from stealing your 'binary' (PDF document).

Comment: Document binaries are transmitted through a middleware to our device that cannot be accessed from the outside. Data is stored only in memory.

Comment: Even then, RMSDK would be the definitive approach of building PDF viewer. BTW, did you try content provider approach of working with installed Reader on Android?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct that Google does not provide a native API to view PDF documents?

Yes it is true

> We could not find any evidence.

Run a [search yourself](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch#search/&exact_package=android&q=pdf%20lang%3a%5Ejava%24&sq=&type=cs)

> Are there any resources available enabling us to implement our own viewer?

Besides the one you've shown there is [andpdf](http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/)

You can try searching if there is an application supporting pdf viewing on the phone. Some phones like Nexus supports this.

```
                Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.your.app/raw/pdfId");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
              // no apps with pdf support, run your own 
              }
```

Comment: This means we cannot use the code, since we do not have any files stored in the filesystem. But thanks!